# Switching user control in WPF only shows the name of ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I've built WPF app using MVVM design with some simple navigation. I added two Views(User Controls) and dummy ViewModels (empty classess) to the project to switch them through this navigation. Here is my folder structure: 
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSEud.jpg)

So when I click i.e. on the first button in navi instead of the view of user control, I got the name of the ViewModel like this:
[App screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwzos.jpg)
(View.ViewModels.NameoftheViewModel)

**Here is how I implemented this:**

[Window.Resources with DataTemplate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8R3G.jpg)

[Navi buttons for switching user controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD3tP.jpg)

MainWindow.xaml.cs :

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new NavigationViewModel();
    }
```

NavigationViewModel used for switching :

```
class NavigationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand CurrencyCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand GoldCommand { get; set; }
    private object selectedViewModel;
    public object SelectedViewModel
    {
        get { return selectedViewModel; }
        set { selectedViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel"); }
    }

    public NavigationViewModel()
    {
        CurrencyCommand = new BaseCommand(OpenCurrency);
        GoldCommand = new BaseCommand(OpenGold);
    }

    public void OpenCurrency(object obj)
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new CurrencyViewModel();
    }

    public void OpenGold(object obj)
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new GoldViewModel();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)

    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }

    }
}
```

BaseCommand class simply implements ICommand interface.

XAML for showing user controls :

```
<ContentControl Margin="45, 50, 0, 0" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
```

Does anyone knows why is this happening? I did this from the tutorial: [Tutorial link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30898.simple-navigation-technique-in-wpf-using-mvvm.aspx) and it works all fine for this tutorial case but in my project it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from linked tutorial:

> Create a DataTemplate of type EmployeeViewModel and it should contain EmployeeView UserControl inside it. *Important thing is you should specify any key to the DataTemplates*, since these DataTemplates are going to get queried by their DataType.

you **should not** specify `x:Key` for DataTemplates for your view models. DataTemplates can be picked by DataType only if there is no x:Key

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CurrencyViewModel}">
    <vs:CurrencyControl/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Can't believe I'm that stupid. It worked, thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry , but this won't works for me !!

Comment: @abdou_dev, it worked for OP 2 year ago. you can easily ask you own question